# peer certificate did not match "smtp.office354.com" using phpmailer

Tags: php, email, server, certificate, phpmailer

Good Day,

I was having an error on my phpmailer smtp configuration to smtp.office365.com

here my script

```
require __DIR__ .'/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require __DIR__ .'/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require __DIR__ .'/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;


$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 4;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.office365.com'); // Specify main and backup SMTP servers

    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'office365 username';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'office365 password';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array (
                        'ssl' => array(
                        // 'verify_peer'  => false,

                        // 'verify_peer_name'  => false,
                        // 'allow_self_signed' => true
                        ));
    $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->From       = $mail->Username;
    $mail->addAddress('recipient@gmail.com');               // Name is optional
    //Attachments

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

I got this error

```
stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`servername.com' did not match expected CN=`smtp.office365.com'
```

if I uncomment

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array (
                        'ssl' => array(
                        // 'verify_peer'  => false,
                        'peer_name'         => 'smtp.office365.com',
                        // 'verify_peer_name'  => false,
                        // 'allow_self_signed' => true
                        ));
```

I still get authentication failure..

Im not really good with server configuration as someone is doing the server set up.  but my site is on https.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what this means. You’re asking to connect to a named host, but the name on the certificate does not match. That means that either the server is misconfigured (unlikely for office365), or you are being redirected to a different server that’s using a different name. This is extremely likely, as it’s very common in large hosting providers. All will be revealed if you set `SMTPDebug = 2`, as the troubleshooting guide the error message links to suggests.

That this has happened is a *good* thing - it’s one of the main reasons for using TLS - it not only encrypts your traffic in transit, but provided assurance that the server you connected to is the one you expected, i.e. it is doing its job properly.

Comment: also one thing.. it was actually working when I configured it the first day, then after a week, I then check it then it started to generate this error.. Im not really sure why..

Comment: Right - that means your SMTP connection is being intercepted and redirected elsewhere, so the name no longer matches. This is TLS doing its job properly, preventing man in the middle attacks, and stopping your credentials being given away to an unknown third party. Check with your ISP what their policy on outbound SMTP is. You may be forced to use their servers, which is bad news if you want to use a Gmail from address.

Comment: thanks for the thought.. also Im not using gmail as from , im actually using the office365 account.. does this affect the issue Sir?

Comment: Ah sorry, my mistake, I meant an office365 address.

Comment: I see .. thanks Sir.. I would check the ISP for this.. glad to know that this is not an error due to my code :) also been spending days on this and I cant seem to match all other answers to my case.. I'll just keep this up for now, incase some other suggestions